# Получить предпоследний заказ для клиента

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть dataframe с некоторым количеством заказов, id клиента и датой заказа. Мне нужно посчитать последний выполненный заказ по клиенту для каждой строки

Я попробовал вытащить максимальное значение id заказа для клиента, но не могу сообразить как ограничить по дате.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [ 133853.0,155755.0,149331.0,337270.0,
  775727.0,200868.0,138453.0,738497.0,666802.0,697070.0,128148.0,1042225.0,
  303441.0,940515.0,143548.0],
 'CLIENT':[ 235632.0,231562.0,235632.0,231562.0,734243.0,
   235632.0,235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,734243.0,235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,
   734243.0,235632.0],
 'DATE_START': [ ('2017-09-01 00:00:00'),
   ('2017-10-05 00:00:00'),('2017-09-26 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-03-23 00:00:00'),('2018-12-21 00:00:00'),
   ('2017-11-23 00:00:00'),('2017-09-08 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-12-12 00:00:00'),('2018-11-21 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-12-01 00:00:00'),('2017-08-22 00:00:00'),
   ('2019-02-06 00:00:00'),('2018-02-20 00:00:00'),
   ('2019-01-20 00:00:00'),('2017-09-17 00:00:00')]})
data.groupby('CLIENT').apply(lambda x:max(x['ID']))
```

В идеале нужно, чтобы было тоже количество строк в dataframe, и был еще столбец в котором указано значение id заказа, который был последним перед текущим заказом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
data['prev_id']= data.sort_values('DATE_START').groupby('CLIENT')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.shift())
```

Или так:

```
data['prev_id']= data.sort_values('DATE_START').groupby('CLIENT').shift()['ID']
```

Comment: Первый вариант сработал) Круто. Второй не совсем подошел, так как доп строку с NaN создает.

Comment: репутации мало) я уже поставил) мой голос учитывается. но не отображается